# Irregular gaps between bars in d3 barchart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I create the bars in my bar chart with the following:

```
var _barPaddingFine = 1;

 // INTRODUCE THE BARS
 var sel = _plot.selectAll("rect")
     .data(TOPbarData);

 // EXIT old elements not present in new data.          
 sel.exit()
     .transition()
     .remove();

 // UPDATE old elements present in new data.
 sel
     .style("fill-opacity", 0.9)
     .transition()
     .duration(_transitionDuration) //1400
     .attr({
         x: function(d, i) {
             return _xScale(d.dt);
         },
         y: function(d) {
             return _yScale(Math.max(0, d.amount));
         },
         width: (quadrantWidth() / TOPbarData.length - _barPaddingFine),
         height: function(d) {
             return Math.abs(_yScale(d.amount) - _yScale(0));
         },
         fill: function(d) {
                 return d.amount < 0 ? "#FF0000" : _currentColr;
             }
     })
     .style("fill-opacity", 1);
```

It produces this:

[image]

The gaps between the bars is not regular e.g. the gap between the 1st and 2nd bars is different than between the 2nd and 3rd.

I'm guessing that the culprit is that the result of the division `quadrantWidth() / TOPbarData.length` is being rounded?

Is there a standard approach I should use to standardize these gaps?

I created a mock-up in Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/kxFB6Z?p=preview
The code I'm looking to amend is in barChart.js around line number 144
In Plunker it renders with nice regular gaps but as you can see from the above screenprint in our production environment that is not the case.

Comment: *Is there a standard approach I should use to standardize these gaps?* Oh, yes: use a band scale (or, since I see you're using v3, an ordinal scale with rangebands)..

Comment: cheers Geraldo -  if the width attribute needs to be dynamic how do I go about implementing an ordinal scale with rangebands?

Comment: Please, share the code which creates that bars in the image, and I'll change it for you.

Comment: thanks Geraldo - let me strip out a self contained bit of code from the visual for you - I'll amend the question later today

Comment: @GerardoFurtado well setting it up in Plunker was a little painful + the gaps are pretty regular when rendered via Plunker but via our production portal they are irregular so if you have some spare time your alternative using ordinal scale with rangebands would be appreciated: http://plnkr.co/edit/kxFB6Z?p=preview